# How to extract data depending on position of first zero?

Tags: import, data

I have a file (attached as an image) which I imported to *Mathematica* and only extracted the first and second column. My problem is that I want to extract the data beginning from the row where $A=0$.
Assuming that the extraction of the 2 columns is called $s$ I could easily use [`Drop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Drop.html) `Drop[s, 13]`, but I want the same for more files in which the `0` is not always at the beginning of the 14th row. I think I should wrap it in a function of the empty entries, but I have no clue how to do it.

Does anyone have suggestions for what my approach should be?

[image: Revamped image description]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your data will be stored as a list of lists, so I'm just approximating that by using random numbers and letting A be list element number one. Then I would do this:

```
data = RandomInteger[10, {20, 3}]
Drop[data, LengthWhile[data, #[[1]] != 0 &]]
```

The new list will always start with a line where A is zero, so for example:

> {{0, 8, 10}, {1, 7, 9}, {5, 1, 5}, {2, 10, 0}, {8, 0, 6}, {3, 1,
>   3}, {1, 5, 0}, {1, 10, 9}, {4, 2, 8}, {8, 4, 1}, {4, 10, 10}, {0, 6,
>   2}, {8, 0, 0}, {8, 4, 10}, {1, 6, 0}, {6, 8, 1}, {9, 1, 9}}

Answer (score 3):

The edited title rather contains a hint to an alternative: [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Position.html)

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomInteger[10, {20, 3}]~Prepend~{"x", "y", "z"};
Drop[data, Position[data, {0, __}, {1}, 1][[1, 1]] - 1]

(* {{0, 2, 6}, {4, 5, 4}, {3, 0, 1}, {3, 5, 3},
    {0, 3, 2}, {3, 9, 5}, {1, 5, 2}, {3, 9, 1},
    {0, 4, 4}, {1, 5, 2}, {7, 9, 9}, {8, 10, 0}, {10, 10, 7}} *)
```

It's pretty fast, but that's not likely to be an issue, unless the first zero occurs rather far down the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

**Using `SequenceReplace`:**

```
SequenceReplace[list, {{Except[0], __} .., k : {_, _, _}} :> k, 1]
```

> {{0, 2, 6}, {4, 5, 4}, {3, 0, 1}, {3, 5, 3}, {0, 3, 2}, {3, 9, 5}, {1,
> 5, 2}, {3, 9, 1}, {0, 4, 4}, {1, 5, 2}, {7, 9, 9}, {8, 10, 0}, {10,
> 10, 7}}

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomInteger[10, {20, 3}];
```

Using `SequenceSplit`:

```
patt = {a_, b__} /; a == 0;

SequenceSplit[data, {s : patt} :> s][[2 ;;]] /. m_?MatrixQ :> Splice@m

(*{{0, 2, 6}, {4, 5, 4}, {3, 0, 1}, {3, 5, 3}, {0, 3, 2}, {3, 9, 5}, {1,5, 2},   
   {3, 9, 1}, {0, 4, 4}, {1, 5, 2}, {7, 9, 9}, {8, 10, 0}, {10, 10, 7}}*)
```

Or using `SplitBy`:

```
SplitBy[data, #[[1]] != 0 &][[2 ;;]] /. m_?MatrixQ :> Splice@m

(*{{0, 2, 6}, {4, 5, 4}, {3, 0, 1}, {3, 5, 3}, {0, 3, 2}, {3, 9, 5}, {1,5, 2},   
   {3, 9, 1}, {0, 4, 4}, {1, 5, 2}, {7, 9, 9}, {8, 10, 0}, {10, 10, 7}}*)
```

I add a very good version that @Syed has provided me:

```
SequenceSplit[data, k : {{0, _, _} ..} :> k] // Rest // Catenate

SplitBy[data, #[[1]] != 0 &] // Rest // Catenate
```

Comment: `SequenceSplit[data, k : {{0, _, _} ..} :> k] // Rest // Catenate` and `SplitBy[data, #[[1]] != 0 &] // Rest // Catenate`

Comment: Thanks, Syed! I've added the versions you just suggested to my answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[1];
list = RandomInteger[10, {20, 3}];
```

Using `DeleteElements` (new in 13.1) and `TakeWhile`

```
DeleteElements[list, TakeWhile[list, #[[1]] != 0 &]]
```

Using `MapAt` and `LengthWhile`

```
MapAt[Nothing, ;; LengthWhile[list, #[[1]] != 0 &]] @ list
```

Using `Part` and `FirstPosition`

```
list[[First @ FirstPosition[list, {0, __}] ;;]]
```

Using `Part` and `Split`

```
list[[Length @ First @ Split[list, #[[1]] != 0 &] ;;]]
```

All produce

{{0, 2, 6}, {4, 5, 4}, {3, 0, 1}, {3, 5, 3}, {0, 3, 2}, {3, 9, 5}, {1,
5, 2}, {3, 9, 1}, {0, 4, 4}, {1, 5, 2}, {7, 9, 9}, {8, 10, 0}, {10,
10, 7}}